# How to add dynamically created image to powerpoint slide?

Tags: vb.net, ms-office, powerpoint

I am creating a PPT file with VB.NET and I would like to insert dynamically created images from memory into the slides, these images are screenshots being put into Image variables.

```
oSlide.Shapes.AddPicture("file location", False, True, 150, 150, 500, 350)
```

Is used to insert an image but it only accepts a file location.

I would rather not save all of the images I am creating to insert then delete off my drive. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Clipboard.SetImage(YouVariableHere)` Load your image to the clipboard first

This function happens to take a `System.Drawing.Image` as it's argument

`Shapes.Paste` pastes whatever is currently on the clipboard.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. There is no mention, that the clipboard is involved in any way.

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. These images are screenshots that do not exist in a file and you don't want to save them to a file. Where else would a screenshot be besides the clipboard?

Comment: *"these images are screenshots being put into Image variables"*

Comment: See updated answer. Please remove down vote, thanks!

Comment: The clipboard belongs to the user, and should only be modified with the user's explicit consent. This is not a recommended solution to the question.

Comment: I think that's debatable :-) I agree in general but at the same time since taking screenshots WITHOUT the use of the clipboard is fairly involved there is a good chance that the OP already violated your "recommendation", so we should really let him be the judge of what is acceptable.

Comment: Guys I really appreciate the concern. This might be a problem for some of my users where it is overwriting their clipboard data... but in the meantime this is the workaround solution I will use, or simply save the data into a cache folder, deleting afterwards which I really don't want to do. But realistically, I would like something like "Shapes.SetImage(image)". @IInspectable

Comment: @JeroenS. This method works! The clipboard is definitely the middleman here, but the user should not need their clipboard while using my application so this is the solution I will use unless something else comes up that can cancel clipboard usage. Thanks so much.

Comment: I agree with Iinspectable, this is a workaround not a solution. From what I have read, the only way you will manage this is by going down the OpenXml route, and to be honest your solution of saving the file temporarily is better than this. how do you know another badly written program won't be abusing the clipboard while yours runs?